# Lost free space after failed Disk Utility operation?

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, partition

I have a 3.1 TB Fusion Drive on an iMac running Sierra, and I wanted to create a new partition (of 1.5 TB). I booted into Recovery Mode and used Disk Utility to create a new volume. However, Disk Utility froze on `Resizing Core Storage Physical Volume Structures`. I quit Disk Utility and rebooted back into Recovery Mode. However, Disk Utility now shows my original partition with 1.5 TB less storage (the size of the new partition). However, using `diskutil list` doesn't show the new partition. How can I get either the storage back or have the new partition appear.

Here the result of `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            121.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *3.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            2.7 TB     disk1s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.1 MB   disk1s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                250.0 GB   disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Macintosh HD           +1.5 TB     disk2
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2, disk1s2
                                 03BC8817-F05E-4FC3-9A5C-50130CDAB3AB
                                 Unencrypted Fusion Drive
```

Here is the result of `diskutil  cs list`:

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group DFD31523-36BE-47AB-A666-54B64038E46B
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         2870717931520 B (2.9 TB)
    Free Space:   1315567517696 B (1.3 TB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume FEC1934B-53F8-49A1-ABE6-5155689D9A68
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     120988852224 B (121.0 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 4F985EA2-E22B-451F-BEB3-E5EF76D14A59
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    1
    |   Disk:     disk1s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     2749729079296 B (2.7 TB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 27D90160-503D-48B7-B434-798CEE738260
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Type:         None
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 03BC8817-F05E-4FC3-9A5C-50130CDAB3AB
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:                  disk2
            Status:                Online
            Size (Total):          1548963545088 B (1.5 TB)
            Revertible:            No
            LV Name:               Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:           Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
            LVG Type:              Fusion, Sparse
```

Here is the result of the `sudo gpt -r show disk1` :

```
       start        size  index  contents
           0           1         PMBR
           1           1         Pri GPT header
           2          32         Pri GPT table
          34           6         
          40      409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
      409640  5370564608      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  5370974248     1269760      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  5372244008        4056         
  5372248064   488284160      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  5860532224         911         
  5860533135          32         Sec GPT table
  5860533167           1         Sec GPT header
```

I do use the bootcamp partition to run Windows. It predates my problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can resize CoreStorage Logical Volumes with the command:

```
diskutil cs resizeVolume lvUUID size
```

with lvUUID: UUID of the Logical Volume and size: a size in b, k, m ,g or t. Depending on your system version a magic size of 0g is also possible. It will expand the Logical Volume to the whole available size of the LVG.

In your case that's either

```
diskutil cs resizeVolume 03BC8817-F05E-4FC3-9A5C-50130CDAB3AB 0g
```

or

```
diskutil cs resizeVolume 03BC8817-F05E-4FC3-9A5C-50130CDAB3AB 2865g
```

If you get an error message like "... partition is too small ...", choose a slightly smaller size like 2864g or 2863g.

---

After a failed add volume/resize command (in your case Disk Utility froze) the innards of the Logical Volume Group are often corrupted and it has to be rebuilt from scratch which requires a (Time Machine) backup.

Adding a 2nd HFS+ volume may render your Windows partition non-bootable.

Comment: When I try to run `diskutil cs resizeVolume`, I get `Error: -69674: The provided Core Storage logical volume has an incorrect size; you should run whole-disk repair`

Comment: Here the second last sentence of my answer applies. First you may try to repair the disk booted to Internet Recovery Mode with `diskutil repairDisk disk0` but this fails usually.